# AWS, Terraform - Create Quicksight Dataset

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-quicksight

I'm working with AWS QuickSight and provisioning it Terrform.  I need to create a QuickSight dataset, analogous to this [command, here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/quicksight/create-data-set.html#create-data-set).  But in the aws provider, no such resource exists.

What is a way that I can create the dataset without straying too far from TF?  I've thought of using a `null-resource` or a `local-exec` but got worried about the messiness.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there an existing feature request in the provider?

Answer (score 2):

There is an [AWS Cloud Control Terraform Provider](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-awscc#terraform-aws-cloud-control-provider) that's currently in Technical Preview, but does provide the following QuickSight resource [awscc_quicksight_data_set](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/awscc/latest/docs/resources/quicksight_data_set) (in addition to 5 others: analysis, dashboard, data_source, template, & theme).  I have not used this provider (yet) but plan to explore it soon for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

Since the resource is not GA yet, in my opinion, the best way to handle the lifecycle using Terraform is to use another Terraform resource. [aws_cloudformation_stack](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudformation_stack). This means that the [Quicksight DataSet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-quicksight-dataset.html) will be created through CloudFormation but the stack resource will be managed by Terraform.

Answer (score 0):

terraform is not providing a resource yet to `create-data-set`. The solution is a bit dirty and needs a bit of json manipulation which ive done via `jq`.

what i did is was first i [terraform creating data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/quicksight_data_source) which you need for data set. then as you can see in [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/quicksight/create-data-set.html#create-data-set) you have two ways to create dataset.

1. using skeleton. which you can create a dataset manually and use its id from URL and describe it via cli and store its skeleton to use for creating a new one. `aws quicksight describe-data-set --aws-account-id <value> --data-set-id <value> >> skeleton.json`
2. creating it via cli params:

   ```
   aws quicksight create-data-set \
   --aws-account-id $target_account_id \
   --data-set-id $DataSetId \
   --name $Name \
   --physical-table-map $PhysicalTableMap \
   --logical-table-map $LogicalTableMap \
   --import-mode $ImportMode
   ```

   however via cli you still need `PhysicalTableMap` which you can get write it manually or again get it via `describe` command.

please note that you need to update data source ARN under physical table map . to do so you need to have `PhysicalTableId` which i get it via `PhysicalTableId=$(awk -F \" '/"PhysicalTableId":/ { print $4 }' skeleton.json)` command. The rest you can do via `jq`.

one last thing to remember, if you are executing bash via terraform, to make it idempotent and execute it everytime you need to add below line:

```
  resource "null_resource" "list_data_sources" {
  triggers = {
    always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {...}
```

here timestamp is different everytime and makes terraform to destroy the resource and create it again which helps you to execute you script on every `apply`.